# Symfony3 customize label of EntityType choices

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I search a solution to customize the label of choice of EntityType.

### Entities

#### Post

```
class Post
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Item", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $items;

    // ...
}
```

### Item

```
class Item
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=127)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;

    // ...

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

### Form

```
class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('items', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Item',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Post'
        ));
    }
}
```

### Result

I know how to modify the DOM to get :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="post_items_1" name="post[items][]" value="1">
        <label for="post_items_1">Item 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="post_items_2" name="post[items][]" value="2">
        <label for="post_items_2">Item 2</label>
    </li>

    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

But I would like get other informations from the Item choices (like property image) :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="post_items_1" name="post[items][]" value="1">
        <label for="post_items_1">
            Item 1
            <img src="/uploads/item/lorem.jpg" alt="" /> <!-- path store into item #1 -->
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="post_items_2" name="post[items][]" value="2">
        <label for="post_items_2">
            Item 2
            <img src="/uploads/item/ipsum.jpg" alt="" /> <!-- path store into item #2 -->
        </label>
    </li>

    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a `choice_label` is what you're looking for:

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
    'choice_label' => 'username',
));
```

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

If you want to use images in your label, you can customize your form template. You can read about it here:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-theming-methods
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming

Comment: Thank you, but I 'm not sure that can help me.

If I use `choice_label => 'username'`, SF calls getUsername() from entity and it must return a string.
In my case, I would like to customize the template form_label with all properties (image for example) of my entity and not just with a string.

It is quite possible that I forget something...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You can create a method (i.e. getLabel()) that returns an array with variables (for example username, image_url and email). You can use that array in your twig template.